# How does the browser handle images in the stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, web-services, http, browser

**Context:** I ran a link sleuth / error checker on my Wordpress website, and found some broken links originating within style.css. These were caused by the theme developer who set up a long list of CSS definitions for certain classes that would load images for them by using the `'background: url()'` property, when the classes are present of course. Well this raised 2 general issues for me as follows, and I searched everywhere but couldn't find the answers (the main question is in the title, can you please think of these as 'sub-questions'?):

1. **Doesn't this way of building style.css load a lot of extra unnecessary cruft into the session?** Maybe not. I am pretty sure that these image files themselves are not actually requested by the browser unless needed by the page, but I am not sure the process of how this works. Is it that the browser gets the stylesheet, parses it in conjunction with the HTML to determine which classes are 'present', and then requests the stylesheet-linked images from the server accordingly? So in that case, the `"background: url(image.png)"` definitions that are unused (due to that class not existing on the page), would just be ignored, and that line of the .css file would represent a link to 'somewhere' that is in the 'namespace' of the DOM, but the line of code just sits there, it isn't acted upon, and the file is not pre-fetched or anything? Do I have this correct, close enough, or how could I learn more about this topic?
2. **What happens if, (as it does in this case which the link sleuth showed me), the image linked to from within the stylesheet actually returns a 404?** I know this is happening because the theme developer forgot to add those assets into the website folder structure. But is the browser itself 'making it to' all of those 404 errors each time it parses the stylesheet (which presumably would impact performance somewhat, or trigger various alerts on my server software and other places due to all of these invalid link requests)? Or again, are those links just ignored since the classes don't exist in this particular instance of the markup, and so they would only be requested case-by-case in the event that the resource is actually **needed** by some code on the site?